# Unable to Override Cancel Order button in Purchase Order screen

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to override the Cancel Order button in Purchase Order screen, but I didn't found the Acumatica existing source code in POOrderEntry.

Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit? The question is so generic.

Comment: Cancel Order button is defined within automation steps [SM205000]

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. As Joshua mentioned it could be set via an automation step which is a setup in Acumatica and not code. If you want to check a condition and stop the cancel you could look at extending the POOrder Cancelled FieldVerifying or perform some logic after updated extend POOrder Cancelled FieldUpdated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can do the following:

```
public class POOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<POOrderEntry>
{
    public MyCancelButton<POOrder> Cancel;
}

public sealed class MyCancelButton<TNode> : PXCancel<TNode> where TNode : class, IBqlTable, new()
{
    public MyCancelButton(PXGraph graph, string name) : base(graph, name)
    {
    }

    public MyCancelButton(PXGraph graph, Delegate handler) : base(graph, handler)
    {
    }
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Cancel", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXCancelButton]
    protected override IEnumerable Handler(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        //DO SOME STAFF HERE
        throw new PXException("Very bad idea");
        return base.Handler(adapter);
    }
}
```

But I **DON'T RECOMMEND** you doing that because the "Cancel" action is doing a lot of very important staff and messing it up is pretty easy.
I recommend considering other ways to do what you want to do. May be to place the logic in the Persisting or Verifying handlers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Samvel Petrosov.

We have implemented this gone for the another approach for this.